# How to identify the Events and Its associated control in (DTE) CodeElement?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-addins

I am writing an Add-in to identify all kind of methods (Function, Procedure and Events) in class;

I want to add specific set of code depending upon the above types. Currently I can able clasify the Functions and Procedures using 
vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction and vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionSub respectively.

How can I identify the Events and its associated Control name using the same.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate the code elements of a file recursively see [HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/). Then, each EnvDTE.CodeElement has a Kind property that allows you to identify in the code element is a namespace, class, event, method, property, delegate, etc. To get the specific properties you can cast the EnvDTE.CodeElement to specific code elements such as EnvDTE.CodeClass, EnvDTE80.CodeEvent. etc.

Now, if you mean that you want to identify methods that are **event handlers** (which is different to identify **events** that a class can raise), there is no easy answer and the code model won't help. For VB.NET you can identify them if they include the "Handles" clause in the declaration, and for C# you need to get the event handler binding in the designer file. Or you can try the [IEventBindingService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.ieventbindingservice.aspx). This other article of mine can help you because if does something related (to bind a method to an event handler): [HOWTO: Add an event handler from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)